# Port database queries

Tags: 7, database

I have inherited a Drupal 6 site with some custom modules, all of which are making use of `db_query()`. Now I'm porting the site with all its modules to Drupal 7, and consequently have to adjust most of the database queries to work with the new DBTNG abstraction layer.

That's fine, but a very tedious task. Is there any automated way to do this, or a module to at least help you on the way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing I know of to take a string `db_query()` value would be the [Query Coder](https://www.drupal.org/project/query_coder) module.

Be aware of its known issues:

**Known issues (taken from project page 01-29-2015):**

- INSERT queries must be specified in form "INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...) VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)"
- Not support "->expression()" conditions for UPDATE queries.
- All tables and fields in SELECT query must be specified with aliases, in other (UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE) queries without aliases
  Example:
  RIGHT: "SELECT * FROM users u"
  NOT RIGHT: "SELECT * FROM users"
- All combining conditions in SELECT queries must be specified with aliases.
  Example:
  RIGHT: "SELECT COUNT(*) AS user_count FROM users u"
  NOT RIGHT: "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users u".

Comment: Wow - looks great! Will check it out! Thanks a lot! Not exactly an automated port, but I guess it will save me some time :)